# Are Private members of base class always inherited in derived class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I used to see everywhere that private members of base class are never inherited in derived class, no matter how you inherit the base class (private or protected or public).

But below question has really confused me up. I don't know why the output of this program is 80. It should be 1 byte (which is the size of an empty class in C++) because private members are never inherited.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
  int arr[10];
};

class b1: public base { };

class b2: public base { };

class derived: public b1, public b2 {};

int main(void)
{
  cout << sizeof(derived);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You saw wrong. Everything from a base class is inherited by derived types.

Comment: The private members are inherited, but not *visible*, in the derived classes.

Comment: "Everything from a base class is inherited by derived types" I'd say: Everything from a **all base classes** is inherited by derived types. That's why you have 80 bytes - sizeof(b1) + sizeof(b2)

Comment: The private members are derived, but are not accessible by any method that is defined in the child class

Comment: Although they can be accessed indirectly. For example, base could have a public, protected or friend function which access arr, that derived could use.

Comment: When the evidence doesn't back up your assumption, you should question the assumption, not the evidence.

Comment: @MagnusHoff They are visible, but not accessible.  They can still hide other declarations of the same name (e.g. a non-member variable or function).

Comment: @aschepler Ugh, indeed. Braino on my part. Thanks :) I'm unfortunately past my edit window for that comment.

Comment: @MagnusHoff They are not only inherited, they are also visible.  They aren't accessible: name look-up will find them, but if it binds the name to the private member, you get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mostly a problem of semantics and what different people refer to with *inherited*. When a type `D` inherits from a type `B`, each `D` object contains a *full* `B` object. From that point of view all of the members are *there* (and some people call this *inherited*). On the other hand, those members are not *accessible* from the members of `D`, and from that point of view the members are as if they were not there (and some people call this *not inherited*).

Private members of a base (no matter what accesibility) are *not* accessible from the derived types (assuming no friendship relationship), but they are there, an object of the derived type contains an object of the base type.

Comment: also note that a derived class can override private member functions of the base class that are declared virtual. The derived class cannot call the base version of those member functions, but it can override them. In that sense the derived class 'inherits' even the private interface of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, derived classes inherit members from all of their base classes.

The keywords private, public and protected affect only the accessibility of the items they are applied to. If something is not accessible in a particular context and you try to use it, the compiler will give you an error.